# how to auto play "addEventListner" of Javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Can I force Javascript's function “addEventListner” to run in “autoplay” mode rather than “onClick”?

Comment: Maybe you should try to use DOMContentLoaded event or jQuery ready()

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are actually trying to do since your question indicates little knowledge about Javascript which isn't bad by itself. But `addEventListener` is a method of DOM elements as represented in context of Javascript. The question is: what event are you looking for? DOMCOntentLoaded is one of several probable options. Maybe you look for load event of some video player or some image instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are searching for the DOMContentLoaded event.
You can find documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

There they use this example:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
    //Do what ever you want here. This is should be your "autoplay"
  });
</script>
```